# In-place row-wise operation on pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this:

```
>>> x = pandas.DataFrame([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [3, 4, 5]], columns=["A", "B", "C"])
>>> print x
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  3  4  5
```

Now I want to normalize `x` by row --- that is, divide each row by its sum.  As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594469/normalizing-a-pandas-dataframe-by-row), this can be achieved with `x = x.div(x.sum(axis=1), axis=0)`.  However, this creates a *new* DataFrame.  If my DataFrame is large, a lot of memory can be consumed in creating this new DataFrame, even though I immediately assign it to the original name.

Is there an efficient way to perform this operation in place?  I want something like `x.idiv()` that provides the `axis` option of `div` but updates `x` in place.  For this specific case I need the division, but sometimes it would also be nice to have similar in-place versions for all the basic operations.

(I can update it in place by iterating over it row-wise and assigning each normalized row back into the original, but this is slow, and I'm looking for a more efficient solution.)

Comment: This issue looks related - https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5104

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this directly in numpy (without creating a copy):

```
In [11]: x1 = x.values.T

In [12]: x1
Out[12]: 
array([[ 1.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  4.],
       [ 3.,  5.]])

In [13]: x1 /= x1.sum(0)

In [14]: x
Out[14]: 
          A         B         C
0  0.166667  0.333333  0.500000
1  0.250000  0.333333  0.416667
```

*Perhaps there ought to be an inplace flag for div...?*

Comment: (Thanks!) Note: I had thought there was an alignment issue here, but there isn't since you are only doing a row average :) ...There might be an issue if you were div-ing with another DataFrame/Series however :s

Comment: Ah, I had been playing with `values` but got tripped up by the fact that `x.values is x.values` is False, and thought it was losing the connection somewhere under the hood.

Comment: @BrenBarn `x.values is x.values` is False... say whaaaat!

Comment: @AndyHayden: It's true!  (At least for me.)

Comment: @BrenBarn I see it too, that's totally confusing. I was wondering if it was a python attributes thing, the ids are different each time you call .values (in ipython)

Comment: @AndyHayden: It seems to be a property that returns a different ndarray object each time, but somehow these ndarray objects are all sharing the same data.