# equivalent of pandas.DataFrame.div but in place instead of copying?

Tags: python, pandas

I am normalizing the rows of a dataframe using the following command:

```
X = X.div(X.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

I am wondering if there is any way to execution this kind of operation in place in order to reduce memory overhead.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In-place row-wise operation on pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853554/in-place-row-wise-operation-on-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will require extra memory only for the single sums column, which is rather unavoidable.  It avoids the allocation of a new DataFrame like X.

```
sums = X.sum(1)
for col in X:
    X[col] /= sums
```