# Apply a weight formula over a Dataframe using Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a Dataframe and am looking to divide the float value of a cell by the sum of the row where it resides. For this I use a numpy formula. This therefore would give me a weight for that cell for that row. I have this dataframe `df1`:

```
                           AA          AB             AC           AD  
2005-01-02 23:55:00      "EQUITY"    "EQUITY"      "EQUITY"     "EQUITY"   
2005-01-03 00:00:00        32.32      19.5299        32.32      31.0455   
2005-01-04 00:00:00      31.9075      19.4487      31.9075      30.3755   
2005-01-05 00:00:00      31.6151      19.5799      31.6151       29.971   
2005-01-06 00:00:00      31.1426      19.7174      31.1426      29.9647
```

I have tried the following so far:

```
import numpy as np

def foo_bar(x):
    if type(x) is not str:
        return x / np.sum(df1, axis=1)
    else:
        return

df = df_numeric.apply(np.vectorize(foo_bar))
```

It seems the sum part of my formula is not properly written as I get the following error:

```
                           AA          AB             AC           AD  
ValueError: ('setting an array element with a sequence.', 'occurred at index AA')
```

Answer (score 4):

The message error is quite informative in this case: **you are trying to set an array element (*x*) with a sequence.**

Try to load your dataframe `df1` in a Python prompt and print the expression `np.sum(df1,axis=1)`: it returns a sequence -a vector- containing the sums of each row. You would need to select the element of this sequence which corresponds to the appropriate row in each case.

You can **try the following**, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594469/normalizing-a-pandas-dataframe-by-row):

`df1.div(df1.sum(axis=1), axis=0)`

`div` will apply element-wise division in your dataframe.

From your `df1` snippet it seems that you have rows with strings (`"EQUITY"`) alternated with rows with numbers, those will give you problems. I suggest you take out any string rows and leave only a dataframe with numbers. You can use the column titles to give significant names to the columns in your dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following bit of code, which uses pandas features instead of an explicit function.

The function [div](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) performs an element wise division. You feed the total sums as a series to that function, and use the row index of your original element to select the appropriate value for division.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4)),columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) 

data['Total'] = data.sum(axis=1)

data_new= data.iloc[:, :-1].div(data["Total"], axis=0)

print data  
print data_new
```

Result:

```
   A  B   C   D  Total
0  0  1   2   3      6
1  4  5   6   7     22
2  8  9  10  11     38
          A         B         C         D
0  0.000000  0.166667  0.333333  0.500000
1  0.181818  0.227273  0.272727  0.318182
2  0.210526  0.236842  0.263158  0.289474
```