# Python Pandas dataframe division error: operation not ' 'safe' '

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, divide

I am trying to normalize some columns of a Pandas DataFrame in Python to their sum. I have the following the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
l_a_2015 = ['Farh','Rob_Sens','Pressure','Septic',10.0,45.,52.,72.51]
l_a_2010 = ['Water_Column','Log','Humid','Top_Tank',58.64,35.42,10.,30.]

df = pd.DataFrame([l_a_2010,l_a_2015],columns=['Output_A','Tonnes_Rem',
                                               'Log_Act_All','Readout','A1','A2','A3','A4'])
```

I would like to normalize the columns `A1`,`A2`,`A3`,`A4` to their sum as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594469/normalizing-a-pandas-dataframe-by-row) - divide each element on a row by the sum of 4 elements.

The first part of this appears to work fine - I get the sum of the last 4 columns, on each row, with this:

```
x,y = df.sum(axis=1).tolist()
```

So, the list `[x,y]` gives me the sum of the first and second rows (last 4 columns). However, when I try to **divide all DataFrame entries on each row by the sum of that row**, then I am having problems:

```
for b,n in enumerate([x,y]):
    for f,elem in enumerate(list(df)[4:]):
        df.iloc[b,f] = (df.iloc[b,f]/n)*100.
```

I get the following error:

```
[Traceback (most recent call last):134.06, 179.50999999999999]

  File "C:\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    df.iloc[b,f] = (df.iloc[b,f]/n)*100.
TypeError: ufunc 'divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

When I use `print df.dtypes` I am getting `float64` for all the columns so I am not sure why the division is not safe.

Is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
       Output_A Tonnes_Rem Log_Act_All   Readout     A1     A2    A3     A4
0  Water_Column        Log       Humid  Top_Tank  58.64  35.42  10.0  30.00
1          Farh   Rob_Sens    Pressure    Septic  10.00  45.00  52.0  72.51

In [8]: cols = df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns.tolist()

In [9]: cols
Out[9]: ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']
```

let's create a view with numeric columns only:

```
In [10]: v = df[cols]

In [13]: df[cols] = v.div(v.sum(axis=1), 0)

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
       Output_A Tonnes_Rem Log_Act_All   Readout        A1        A2        A3        A4
0  Water_Column        Log       Humid  Top_Tank  0.437416  0.264210  0.074593  0.223780
1          Farh   Rob_Sens    Pressure    Septic  0.055707  0.250682  0.289677  0.403933
```

an alternative way to select `A*` columns:

```
In [18]: df.filter(regex='^A\d+')
Out[18]:
         A1        A2        A3        A4
0  0.437416  0.264210  0.074593  0.223780
1  0.055707  0.250682  0.289677  0.403933

In [19]: df.filter(regex='^A\d+').columns
Out[19]: Index(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I just realized that the post I linked to ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594469/normalizing-a-pandas-dataframe-by-row)) contained the same approach. I didn't think that would work with the non-numeric columns in my dataframe. Your approach is more intuitive with the explanations. Thanks again!